# What is supposed to happen in Verilog if a signal of one width is assigned to another signal of a different width?

Tags: verilog

As in these two cases:

```
wire [3:0] A, B;
wire [4:0] C, D;

assign A = C;  // larger width to smaller width
assign D = B;  // smaller width to larger width
```

What should A and D look like in terms of C and B respectively?

Comment: it ought to spit at you both times, as you clearly don't know what you're doing. I've only ever been nice to it and assigned equal sized things. It might try and guess, or align LSB, I wait with bated breath for the answer.

Comment: Knowing this information is invaluable when debugging simulations. Obviously I don't intentionally code this way, but it'd be really convenient to know the convention so that I can recognize it when I accidentally have coded a mismatch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Verilog's rules are:

- if you copy a narrower value into a wider target, it is zero-extended (zero MSBs added to the left), or sign-extended into the target. Whether it is zero or sign-extended is determined by the signedness of the right-hand-side expression.
- if you copy a wider value to a narrower target, it gets truncated (MSBs removed on the left).

So it means, in your case:

```
assign A = C[3:0];
assign D = { 1'b0, B };
```

Note that most synthesis tools will issue a warning in these cases. And they should because it's then unclear you're doing things correctly.

Comment: I was wondering this for simulation, as the simulator didn't issue warnings. If I had tried synthesis then I am sure it would have. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Indeed, pure simulators may not show warnings, because they care more about pure Verilog's specifications than whether your code is meaningful. You'll see that synthesis tools may potentially leverage a lot of things that simulations tools don't.